# highlighting a <li> element on click and keeping it highlighted even after page load

Tags: c#, javascript, html, css

hi i am applying css to one of my list  elements which is inside a

tag which is in a master page. so when i click this link the style is getting applied but the page reloads and then the applied style is again reset to default this is my code can somebody help me with this? please?

```
 function SelectThis(ctrl) {
        debugger;
        var list = document.getElementById("myslidemenu").getElementsByTagName('a');

        for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            list[i].style.color = "white";
            list[i].style.background = "#414141";
        }
        ctrl.style.background = "black";
        ctrl.style.color = 'yellow';
    }
```

but since i am clicking on a hyper link. the master page reloads and the selected styles are lost

Comment: I don't know about c# and master pages, but... maybe you could save changed/selected style in javascript cookie, or prevent default behavior, so there will be no reload?

Comment: i tried doing document.cookie = selectedControl but i am only getting the hyperlink of that control when i read that cookie can you please elaborate on how this can be done? @nevermind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is a hyper link is residing inside the `<li>` use

e.preventDefault(); will stop the default action of the `<a>` tag

Update:

`list[i].addEventListener('click',preventReload);`

```
function preventReload(e){
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Add this code inside the for loop, which will stop the default functionality of the hyperlink i.e., stops the page from reloading.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the page to reload, because it's a menu to sub pages then the way I do this is to:

1. Define a class for the style
2. Compare the current page url to the a href url (various ways to do this and various levels of matching)
3. If they match apply the class to that element

I would do this server side, not with javascript.

Another option is to use a cookie/session variable, not sure on the C# syntax, I did this recently in PHP and used AJAX to set a session variable after filtering some data to remember the current state when clicking down to the next level.